# Is there a way to get reminders on iPhone to persist until they're checked?

Tags: ios, reminders

I find reminders pretty useless because once you're reminded once it doesn't remind you ever again, even if you haven't completed the task yet. It would actually be useful if every time I looked at my phone it displayed the reminder until I completed it.

Comment: If no one is able to help you hack reminders, you could look into a third party task management app like [things app](
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/things/id284971781?mt=8) to have your reminders persist until cleared.

Answer (score 9):

This is a problem os-wide in iOS, for other apps too, like calendars.  Once you have received your alarm notification, whether for a reminder, or a calendar alert etc, you're done.  There's no way to "snooze" or "remind me later" for these functions.

The only way to get this functionality at present, is to use a replacement app.  One such app is [Due](http://www.dueapp.com), the following blurb is copied from their website:

---

PERSISTENT REMINDERS
WITH AUTO SNOOZE

Overdue reminders stay in sight until you're ready to act on them.

And with auto snooze, your todo list never gets stale.

By default, DUE repeatedly notifies you of overdue reminders every minute* with its auto snoozing feature until you mark them complete, reschedule them, or turn off their auto snooze.

*Auto snooze interval can be changed to every minute, every hour, or none at all. There are no finer auto snooze intervals on iOS due to system limitation.

---

Comment: What's *really* needed is a persistent reminder application that can except Siri input. Is there any third third-party application to reach into the stock iOS Reminders app, as OmniFocus can? Then you could do it.

Answer (score 3):

I found one that, at least at first impression, repeats its notifications until you acknowledge it, and, as I personally require, can have reminders created via Siri (via scooping them out of the stock reminders app).

It's called "[Alarmed](https://appsto.re/us/aROkw.i)".

The only thing that annoys me so far, is when you accidentally check an item as completed, there are multiple steps required to undo it.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Alarmed](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/alarmed-reminders-timers/id371886784?mt=8). Simple yet customizable and integrates with Reminders and Siri.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, there's currently no stock option (like a snooze, for example) of having Reminders.app repeatedly remind you about an item.

iOS 6 *did* introduce the badge device to the icon, though. So they're making progress!

**Edit:** Normally, though, unless you actually go into Reminders.app from the notification on your device, it should still display the reminder(s) among your Notifications.

Comment: If you constantly check your notifications... :) Though it is a good idea to put reminders right at the top of the notifications list.

Answer (score 2):

A good repeating nagging reminder app is iReminder. It's on my home screen. You can set it to nag you at intervals other than the stock 1 min or 1 hour

Answer (score 2):

With the iOS 7 update, reminders can persist on the notification centre.

To configure it, go to *Settings* > *Notification Centre* > Make sure *Today View* is enabled > Make sure *Reminders* is enabled.

Now, when you pull the Notification Centre from the top, your reminders will be listed under the Today tab.